# Java 14 records with org.json

Tags: java, json, org.json, java-record

I wanted to make new JSON object with org.json library, but I have noticed there is a problem with Java 14 records.

When I call

```
String json = new JSONObject(new Order("", "Albert", "GOOGL", "SELL", 97.9, 90L)).toString();
```

the fields are null.

I suppose it is because java record doesn't use old getters like getXYZ?

Is there a simple work around? I mean without using different library.
Or maybe my assumptions are incorrect.

```
public record Order(
    String id,
    String userId,
    String securityId,
    String type,
    Double price,
    Long quantity
) {
}

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    <version>20220320</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Newer Java version support is still [an open item on org.json roadmap](https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java/issues/614). On the other hand I don't know if `record` is mere syntactic sugar or something more involved to the point where it would be not properly interpreted by older libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to use other libraries like **Jackson** or **Gson** (it will be a much better solution in my opinion) you could write your own converter:

```
public final class JsonConverter {

    private JsonConverter() {
    }
    
    @SneakyThrows
    public static String toJSON(Object object) {
        Class<?> c = object.getClass();
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        for (Field field : c.getDeclaredFields()) {
            field.setAccessible(true);
            String name = field.getName();
            Object value = field.get(object);
            jsonObject.put(name, value);
        }
        return jsonObject.toString();
    }
}
```

You could use it like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Order order = new Order("", "Albert", "GOOGL", "SELL", 97.9, 90L);
    System.out.println(order);

    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(order);
    System.out.println(jsonObject.toString());

    System.out.println(JsonConverter.toJSON(order));
}
```

Output:

```
OrderRecord[id=, userId=Albert, securityId=GOOGL, type=SELL, price=97.9, quantity=90]
{}
{"quantity":90,"price":97.9,"securityId":"GOOGL","id":"","type":"SELL","userId":"Albert"}
```

It is a real workaround. However, it uses exactly `org.json`.

Comment: What will be the output if records contains custom user defined class as field?

Comment: It will be invalid json, since it will use toString method of that class to represent it

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. However, the current answer matches the original question from OP - use org.json and print JSON for the Order record.

Comment: Speaking of borderline cases, as was the case with the toString method in my answer, I thought we should also mention this. Problem is that your answer wont work in all scenarios where you have custom user defined object as a field in record. Btw, yes it matches the part "use org.json", but it doesn't matches the part " simple work around".Cheers

Answer (score -1):

According to [documentation](https://stleary.github.io/JSON-java/org/json/JSONObject.html)  JSONObject(Object bean) constructor

construct a JSONObject from an Object using bean **getters**.

So, yes as you noticed it expects getter to be in format getFieldName(), but in records getters are named differently.

For, example getter for filed price would be `price()`, not `getPrice()`.

One possible solution is to add getters in record class, like this :

```
   public record Order(
            String id,
            String userId,
            String securityId,
            String type,
            Double price,
            Long quantity
    ) {
    
    
        public Double getPrice() { // Compliant
            return price;
        }
    
        public String getId() { // Compliant
            return id;
        }
    
        public String getSecurityId() { // Compliant
            return securityId;
        }
    
        public String getType() { // Compliant
            return type;
        }
    
        public Long getQuantity() { // Compliant
            return quantity;
        }
    }
```

You should see output like this :

[image]

Comment: You last solution based on toString is not good, if you string concatenate, you need to make sure to properly escape special characters. You are not forming a proper json string, so jsonobject is going to complain

Comment: @Ferrybig "if you string concatenate, you need to make sure to properly escape special characters" - Where do you see string concatenation in my solution?

Comment: @Nemanja In your last code, you are doing string concatenation though `String.format`. It is not going to magically escape all the quotes in the raw data. Uncontrolled user input can be used to make the json representation different than the methods of the record type.

Comment: @Ferrybig oh, ok we use different terminology .I agree that String.format also does concatenation of strings, but usually by concatenation I mean adding strings with '+' .
I agree that what you wrote can happen. But the solution with getters will work.

Comment: So It turns out that the simplest workaround for this is to use reflection with custom defined JSON converter class ..lol

Comment: @Nemanja I tried to run this code with explicit getters on **JDK 18.0.1** and it prints empty JSON `{}`

Comment: @catch23 I run this code on my machine witch uses jdk 16 and it works without any issue. I didn't tested it on JDK 18 but don't see reason why it shouldn't work.https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-6211

Comment: @Nemanja it works only when the record is public.

Comment: @catch23 I'm not aweare that we can create non public records.